# NoSuchAlgorithmException on running my application

Tags: java, exception

I have changed my JDK from 1.6 to JDK1.8.0_121. But I get the following exception when I run a cmd job.

```
WRAPPED EXCEPTION (Depth 1): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: algorithm RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding is not available from provider Cryptix
END WRAPPED EXCEPTION (Depth 1)
    at dd.tech.crypto.CryptoManagerImpl.encrypt(CryptoManagerImpl.java:385)
    at dd.tech.crypto.CryptoManagerImpl.encrypt(CryptoManagerImpl.java:408)
    at dd.proserv.app.partner.thd.supplychain.docconversion.SCLTXMLCreator.encrypt(SCLTXMLCreator.java:2956)
    at dd.proserv.app.partner.thd.supplychain.docconversion.SCLTXMLCreator.addPaymentItemDataToMap(SCLTXMLCreator.java:1198)
    at dd.proserv.app.partner.thd.supplychain.docconversion.LoadXMLData.endElementAction(LoadXMLData.java:274)
    at dd.sharelib.impexp.docconversion.XMLFileParserBase.endElement(XMLFileParserBase.java:138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
```

I have added **Unlimited Strength Java(TM) Cryptography
Extension (JCE) Policy Files for the Java(TM) Platform, Standard
Edition (Java SE) Runtime Environment 8** to jre/lib/security but there is still same exception.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: [Cryptix](http://www.cryptix.org/)? Have you tried [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) instead?

Comment: Its an existing project and I am newbie to Cryptix :(